# Show $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{\alpha_i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i$ using convexity.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{\alpha_i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i$$ where $\alpha_i $ positive scalars with $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$ and $x_i$ are positive scalars.

I thought to express  $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{\alpha_i} = \exp\left(\sum\alpha_i\log x_i\right)$ as the first step but cannot figure out what to do next. Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your notation $\alpha^i$ does not make sense. The subscript or power must be a subscript.

Comment: yes it was a typo. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 7):

Well, use Jensen's Inequality for the concave function $\ln$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\alpha_i \,\ln\left(x_i\right)\leq \ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\,\alpha_i\,x_i\right)\,.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to deal with $\sum$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your question means?

Comment: @Malintha $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \ln(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i^{\alpha_i}=\ln \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $\ln(x)$ is an increasing function of $x(>0)$.