# How to prove that $\prod_{i=1} ^ \infty x_i^{a_i} \leq \sum_{i=1} ^ \infty a_ix_i$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, infinite-product, jensen-inequality

Let $a_1,a_2,...$ be nonnegative numbers whose sum is $1$ and let $x_1,x_2,...>0$. I want to show that $\prod_{i=1} ^ \infty x_i^{a_i} \leq \sum_{i=1} ^ \infty a_ix_i$.

This looks awfully similar to the $AM \geq GM$ inequality. In fact, the AM-GM inequality is a special case of this.

I was thinking of using Jensen's inequality which states, if a function $\phi$ is convex on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\phi \circ f$ is nonnegative on $[0,1]$, then $\phi(\int_0 ^1 f)\leq \int_0 ^1 \phi \circ f$.

Comment: Also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2865488/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D1%7D%20%5E%20%5Cinfty%20x_i%5E%7Ba_i%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%20%5E%20%5Cinfty%20a_ix_i%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be the measure on the power set of $\mathbb N$ with $\mu \{n\}=a_n$. Let $\phi (x) =-\log x$. $\phi$ is convex.  Apply Jensen's inequality to $f(n)=x_n$.

Comment: I love the abstraction of this proof!

Answer (score 0):

In case the $a_i$ are rational, this is the AM-GM inequality (use a common denominator).  But also both sides are continuous, so you get the real case in the limit.